# How do I subset a list with mixed data type and data structure?

Tags: r

I have a list which included a mix of data type (character) and data structure (dataframe).

I want to keep only the dataframes and remove the rest.

```
> head(list)

[[1]]
[1] "/Users/Jane/R/12498798.txt error"

[[2]]
                                                                                                                                            match
1  Japan arrests man for taking gun
2                                                                                                              Extradition bill turns ugly
                                                     file
1 /Users/Jane/R/12498770.txt
2 /Users/Jane/R/12498770.txt

[[3]]
[1] "/Users/Jane/R/12498780.txt error"
```

I expect the final list to contain only dataframes:

```
[[2]]
                                                                                                                                            match
1  Japan arrests man for taking gun
2                                                                                                              Extradition bill turns ugly
                                                     file
1 /Users/Jane/R/12498770.txt
2 /Users/Jane/R/12498770.txt
```

Comment: Try `list[sapply(list, inherits, "data.frame")]`. Or, simpler, `list[sapply(list, is.data.frame)]`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I tried using that but it showed the error `Error in list[sapply(results, is.data.frame)] : 
  object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable`

Comment: No, in the question the object is named `list`, not `results`. If it's the latter, then try `results[sapply(results, is.data.frame)]`.

Comment: Based on your example, the expected output shows `.txt` links instead of `data.frame`.  I am guessing that you need to remove the ones having `error` substring.  If that is the case `list[!sapply(list, function(x) any(grepl("error$", x)))]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example, it is possible that the OP's `list` elements are `vectors` and want to remove `any` element having 'error' substring

```
list[!sapply(list, function(x) any(grepl("error$", x)))]
```